# Sharing mouse, keyboard, and screen between networked computers

Tags: kvm-switch, screen-sharing, synergy

I've already heard of [Synergy+](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/). I remember hearing of another program that did pretty much the same thing, but allowed you to move windows from one screen to the other, even on different computers.

If I remember correctly, it used talked to X servers on both computers to be able to pass windows back and forth.

Does anyone know of a program that does this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [**Distributed Multihead X Project**](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/) (DMX) is doing this:

> Current Open Source multihead
>   solutions are limited to a single
>   physical machine. A single X server
>   controls multiple display devices,
>   which can be arranged as independent
>   heads or unified into a single
>   desktop. These solutions are limited
>   to the number of physical devices that
>   can co-exist in a single machine
>   (e.g., due to the number of AGP/PCI
>   slots available for graphics cards).
>   Thus, large tiled displays are not
>   currently possible. This limitation
>   will be solved by **eliminating the
>   requirement that the display devices
>   reside in the same physical machine**.
>   This will be accomplished by
>   developing a **front-end proxy X
>   server that will control multiple
>   back-end X servers** that make up the
>   large display. **These X servers can
>   either run on the same or separate
>   machines**.

But according to the [Download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dmx/files/):

> The DMX software has been integrated
>   into the X.org server software. Please
>   download directly from X.org instead
>   of from SourceForge. The code here is
>   rather old and is no longer updated.

Comment: I knew it was too good to be true... 8-]